# .loc changing multiple columns involuntarily

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
Location    Field       Value       Count
01          Ethnicity   minority    124
02          Gender      male        96
03          Religion    minority    115
04          Gender      female      132
```

I'm using `.loc` to change the values in `Value` to 0, 1 instead of text. When I use `df.loc[df['Value'] == 'male'] = 0`
`Value` changes, but so does `Field`. How do I avoid this happening?

Also, this DF was created straight from a CSV file, and this is the first change I'm making so it's not like I'm piling functions on top of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the column:

```
df.loc[df['Value'] == 'male', 'Value'] = 0

print(df)
   Location      Field     Value  Count
0         1  Ethnicity  minority    124
1         2     Gender      0        96
2         3   Religion  minority    115
3         4     Gender    female    132
```

Or use np.where to do all the conversions:

```
df['Value'] = np.where(df['Value'].eq('male'), 0, 1)

print(df)
   Location      Field  Value  Count
0         1  Ethnicity      1    124
1         2     Gender      0     96
2         3   Religion      1    115
3         4     Gender      1    132
```

Comment: your `np.where` statement turns all the rows of `Value` to 1. The `df.loc[df['Value'] == 'male', 'Value'] = 0` works.

Comment: Yeah, that's just how I defined it using np.where.  It's saying, set df['Value'] to 0 if df['Value'] equals male, otherwise set it to 0.  It's like IF statements in excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `pandas.DataFrame.replace`

```py
df.replace({'Value': {'male':0, 'female':1}})
```

This will return a new dataframe with the values replaced.

```
   Location      Field     Value  Count
0         1  Ethnicity  minority    124
1         2     Gender         0     96
2         3   Religion  minority    115
3         4     Gender         1    132
```